# PHP Arrays : Mathematical operations with multiple arrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a logical problem here as to how I should execute this in PHP, your support is much appreciated
I have two arrays:

1. Invoice
2. Payment

The arrays look like this

```
$invoice = array
(
    array("id"=>1,"amt"=>2000.00),
    array("id"=>2,"amt"=>3000.00),
    array("id"=>3,"amt"=>4000.00)
);


$payments = array
(
    array("id"=>11111,"amt"=>500.00),
    array("id"=>22222,"amt"=>3000.00),
    array("id"=>33333,"amt"=>4500.00),
    array("id"=>44444,"amt"=>1500.00)
);
```

**UPDATE**
this is the code that i have written.

```
    // count how many elements available
$sc = count($iSetl);
$ic = count($payments);

/*
    Three types of flags
    $flag = 0   //  first execution
    $flag = 1   //  settlement amount is higher than the payment amount
    $flag = 2   //  payment amount is higher than the settlement amount

*/

// available balances after transaction
$setBal = 0;   // settlement balance
$paymBal = 0;   // payment balance
$flag = 0;

// our priority is to disburse all payments
// therefore our initial loop would be payments
foreach($payments as $p){

    // round 2:
    // settlement value is higher there for we are approaching to the next invoice
    if($flag == 1){
        if($setBal > 0){
            if($setData <= $p["amt"]){
                $setData = $p["amt"] - $setData;
                //echo($setData)."<br />";
                $output = "invoice number #".$s["id"]." | invoice value ".$s["amt"]." Payment Number " . $p["id"] . " - Payment Amount ". $p["amt"]."<br />";
                $output .= "after settlement the invoice value is ". $setData;
                echo($output);
                echo "<br />the payment value is more than the invoice settlement <br /><br />";
                $setBal = $setData;
                $flag = 2;
            }
        }
    }

    // start looping each settlements
    foreach($iSetl as $s){

        // check if this is the initial transaction
        if($flag == 0 ){

            // if the settlement balance is equal to 0 (or less)
            // or settlement is complete
            if($setBal <= 0) {

                // this case: Settlement amount is more than the payment amount therefore
                // deduct the settlement from payment
                $setData = $p["amt"];
                $setData = $s["amt"] - $setData;

                $output = "invoice number #".$s["id"]." | invoice value ".$s["amt"]." Payment Number " . $p["id"] . " - Payment Amount ". $p["amt"]."<br />";
                $output .= "after settlement the invoice value is ". $setData;
                echo($output);
                //echo($setData)."<br />";
                echo "<br />the invoice settlement value is more than the payment value<br /><br />";

                // assign the balance amount to be settled
                $setBal = $setData;

                // set the flag as 1 since the settlement value is higher than payment value
                $flag = 1;
            }
        }

        if($flag == 2 ){
            // if the settlement balance is equal to 0 (or less)
            // or settlement is complete
            if($setBal > 0) {
                echo("stage3 <br />");
                // this case: Settlement amount is more than the payment amount therefore
                // deduct the settlement from payment
                $setData = $s["amt"] - $setData;

                //echo($setData)."<br />";
                $output = "invoice number #".$s["id"]." | invoice value ".$s["amt"]." Payment Number " . $p["id"] . " - Payment Amount ". $p["amt"]."<br />";
                $output .= "after settlement the invoice value is ". $setData;
                echo($output);
                echo "<br />the invoice settlement value is more than the payment value<br /><br />";

                // assign the balance amount to be settled
                $setBal = $setData;

                // set the flag as 1 since the settlement value is higher than payment value
                $flag = 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to settle the invoice 'amt' with the payment 'amt' at times the invoice 'amt' is higher than the payment 'amt' amount and at other times the payment is higher than the invoice amount.

The result should show as

[image]

really confused how to approach at this, please help.

Comment: can you explain the logic what you applied to create your table? Because i am unable to understand the logic. Then only any-one able to answer

Comment: hi I have updated the script that i have written. please advice

Comment: What I intend to do is, settle all the invoices against the payments available in the respective arrays. At times invoices cannot be settled (payments) completely, at these situations I need to get to the next available array element from the payments. The same happens when the settled payments have leftover where I would want to settle the next invoice array element. The table I've displayed is the result I expect from the two arrays I've mentioned above. Hope this is clear.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to sorting this can you create an array with array merge, and can sort this array.

This is the php sort method:

```
http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php
```

OR

```
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php
```

You need add the column in callback function for comparison

But, if these data is coming from database, try from sub query and sort by the column.

etc... Order by 'ASC'

Comment: The problem I have is not sorting, I need to settle the invoices as per the payments in the payments array against the invoices.